# Auto changing page title

Tags: reactjs, next.js, autocomplete

Does anybody know a way program or technique to change the title of any page based on the first founded  tag? f.e.

For the most part, they resemble each other so it might be useful to implement it as default parameter, at least

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nextjs it's pretty simple to use [Next-Seo,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo).This will render out the tags in the  for SEO. At a bare minimum, you should add a title and description.

```js
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';

const Page = () => (
  <>
    <NextSeo
      title="Simple Usage Example"
      description="A short description goes here."
    />
    <p>Simple Usage</p>
  </>
);

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-helmet`. You can set the title same as the content of your first div.

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet>
        <title>this is the title</title> // this can be a prop or a state data
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
}
```

DEMO

[image: Edit cool-rain-ckjpk1]

[PREVIEW](https://ckjpk1.csb.app/)